# Eclipse, own TreeViewer with file attributes in Project Explorer View

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, treeviewer

I'm writing Eclipse plugin. One of many features is create Tree with File Attributes like **.java** files have (if you click on .java File in Eclipse you can see whole list with what classes or methods this file have).

I can create this tree with separate view, it isn't problem (I have data,using TreeViewer and everything works great), but now I must create this tree in Project Explorer View and I don't know how.
Maybe should I write because it isn't obviously. This tree won't be display with .java file but with **.txt** file.

So read about this. What I know for now:

1. I should have ***org.eclipse.ui.decorators*** extension point. I already have it
2. My class should ***extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator*** . It already has it

Also I can get access to already selection File , Project , Folder (by using `decorate()` method).
I can add prefix/suffix to already select file ,add icons into File but...

**I'm not seeing any methods what give me possibility add any attributes to file**.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you mean by 'attributes'. What do you want to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the extension points to provide *content*, not *labels*, just as your existing trees (hopefully) use *content* providers for those details.  Start at http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/cnf.htm .

Comment: I'm affraid Im not still understand also it's possible solve my problem without your framework ?,only 'clear' Java.
Yes,my existing TreeViewe on separate view using Content Provider and LabelProvider.

Comment: The `Project Explorer` is built using that framework. It is *the* way to implement what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*nitind* has right , if someone wants implement outline with Project Explorer,use Common Navigator Framework.

Here is simply examples,wrote by creator this framework,how to do this :

1. http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/2006/05/building-common-navigator-based-viewer.html // create view
2. http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/2006/05/building-common-navigator-based-viewer_22.html // create outline

Just try copy this example into your project.

Thx nitind for advice.